# What is a good way to report on changes to documents in sharepoint 2007

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2007, document-library

I've been requested to implement a means of reporting on add/update/deletes on files stored sharepoint (MOSS 2007). After a little bit of research I found out sharepoint has out of the box document auditing which I enabled a couple days ago. I ran the report today, but excel spreadsheet was not very easy to look at.

Also I'm not positive of this, but I believe only site collection administrators can generate thsi audit report, and I dont really want to give the people who want these reports that much permission.

I'm curious what are some alternatives or recommendations? Should I try and get this information off the sQL Server and display it in reporting services, or perhaps try and build a include it in a dashboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the SSRS instance for SharePoint, you can get the report file. You can then make a copy and edit for the report you would like. permissions are a separate issue that can be tackled however you desire, especially if you create a copy and store as a new report.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't initially sure what you meant but after doing some searching on what you had said this worked for me.